# Validation Error in FormGroup level not working

Tags: angular

I have a custom validation in the FormGroup level as defined below:

```
this.createForm = this.builder.group({
  pass: this.builder.control('',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5)
    ]),
  conPass: this.builder.control('',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5)
    ]),
}, { validator: [isTheSame('pass', 'conPass')] });
```

---

```
static isTheSame(c1: string, c2: string): ValidatorFn {
   return (form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const c1Input = form.controls[c1]?.value;
      const c2Input = form.controls[c2]?.value;

      return (c1Input !== c2Input) ? { notTheSame: true } : null;
   };
}
```

I want to check if the `notTheSame` is true or not. I used *`ngIf="createForm .errors?.notTheSame"` and display a text if it returns `true`. But it doesn't work even `notTheSame` has a value of `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set errors on the control level,
here I'm attaching code you can use to achieve your desired results.

you can create one function in one service file

**service.ts**

```
static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password = control.get('pass').value;
    const confirmPassword = control.get('conPass').value;
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      control.get('conPass').setErrors({ passwordNotMatched: true });
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And you can use it in your form during initialization

**component.ts**

```
this.createForm = this.builder.group({
  pass: this.builder.control('',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5)
    ]),
  conPass: this.builder.control('',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5)
    ]),
}, { validator: UtilityService.MatchPassword });
```

And in your HTML

```
<p *ngIf="formName['conPass'].errors && formName['conPass'].errors.passwordNotMatched">Password not matched </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
createForm.hasError(‘notTheSame’)
```

Btw, createForm.errors is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it worked for you.
Html

```
<span class="text-danger *ngIf="createForm.get('conPass')?.hasError('notEquivalent') && createForm.get('conPass')?.touched">Password and Confirm password not matched.</span>
```